# Editable combobox text scrolling

Tags: wpf

I have an editable wpf combobox. When I type something longer than its length instead of scrolling to the last character, the text goes out of the control and its not visible. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
  <ComboBox Margin="11,0,0,0"
            Height="23"                                
            Width="200"
            IsEditable="True"
            Text="{Binding Profile.Mat}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}"  />
```

[image: textscrolling]

Comment: Was this ever solved? It's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by handling the SelectionChanged event of the TextBox inside the ComboBox's template. Add the following code in your code behind :

```
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            if (comboBox.ApplyTemplate())
            {
                TextBox editableTextBox = (TextBox)comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox);
                editableTextBox.SelectionChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(editableTextBox_SelectionChanged);
            }
        }

        void editableTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.ScrollToHome();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Let me know if this what you needed.